# Showing $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n(\cos (\frac{x}{n}))}{(1+x^n)e^x} dx$ exists and computing it.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I need to show the following limit both exists, and compute it.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n(\cos (\frac{x}{n}))}{(1+x^n)e^x} dx$$

So my thoughts were to swap the $\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)$ into $e$ and cancelling out an $e^x$ term from the top and bottom but then you have an $e$ with a messy exponent. To show it exists, can I show its bounded above by the integral of $\dfrac{1}{e^x}$ which is integrable. Is this because both $\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)$ and $\dfrac{x^n}{(1+x^n)}$ tend to (have an absolute value of) $1$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$? or since the function is not increasing, I cannot interchange the limit and integral?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem is not the only theorem you can use to interchange limit and integral. Use dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Good point! @Dan thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit in question evaluates to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{(1+x^n)e^x}\:dx = \int_0^1 0\:dx + \int_1^\infty\cos(0)\cdot e^{-x}\:dx = \frac{1}{e}$$

by dominated convergence, separately on each interval.

Comment: see that's what I was trying to do, bound it somehow using DCT.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame But you incorrectly assumed that $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ tends to $1$. You can apply dominated convergence separately to the two integrals and have a better time of finding an appropriate upper bound.

Comment: I see why its zero on $(0,1)$ but why is cosine being evaluated at $0$ on $(1,\infty)$

Comment: aha you're right, on the the separete intervals it has different limits.

Comment: oh is it cause as $n \rightarrow \infty$ $\frac{x}{n} \rightarrow 0$?